# Call react component from outside

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is that possible to call react component from outside? 
For example

**HTML**

```
<div id='react-app'></div>

<button onClick=callReactModal()>PressME</button>
```

**My component where i want call method**

```
let callReactModal = function () {
  console.log('clicked');
  //Navigation.sayHello();
}

class Navigation extends React.Component<any, any> {

  constructor(props:any){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      language: {
        lang: cookie.load('lang') || ''
      }
    };
    this.click = this.click.bind(this);
  }

  sayHello = () => {
    alert("Hello");
  }
}
```

I have to call Modal from another component but i don't know how to achieve that.

Trying to call method which update `state` in class and getting `Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component.`  It needs to open modal ( Using semantic-ui )

**method which uses state**

```
handleOpen = (e) => this.setState({
        modalOpen: true,
    })
```

**modalPart**

```
<Modal size='small'
                   open={this.state.modalOpen}
                   onClose={this.handleClose}
                   trigger={<a className="btn btn-base" onClick={this.handleOpen}>Login</a>}
                   closeIcon='close'>
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: you need to define sayHello `static` but the question is why?

Comment: Tells me ``Uncaught ReferenceError: callReactModal is not defined``

Comment: look in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odzck2a3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not the best practice. You have to set callReactModal function in the window

```
window.callReactModal = function () {
  console.log('clicked');
  //Navigation.sayHello();
}
```

A better way to implement it, is to create an event listener that opens the modal when triggered.

Comment: This is correct, but like Hoyen said, you probably shouldn't do this. Best to keep everything inside of your react component if possible.

Comment: or create a component with the modal

Comment: agree this is bad practice 
but it essential to use it like this 
Thanks you guys!

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. All your "custom tags"(React Components) should be inside your JSXs. But you can render multiple React apps per page if you want:

```
<div id='react-app'></div>    
<div id='react-button'></div>
```

Comment: it is possible, either by attaching it to window or coding it inside <script></script> tags with the in-browser babel transpiler, though not a good practice either way

Comment: Good to know :)